# Find multiple in string

Tags: regex, go

How I can find multiple value in brackets?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\{[A-Za-z0-9]*\}`)
    s := "{tag1} SomeText {tag2}"
    fmt.Println(re.FindStringSubmatch(s))
}
```

This code return only first tag `tag1`.

https://play.golang.org/p/T8lhGpzfOBj

Comment: I think you could use [FindAllStringSubmatchIndex](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatchIndex) like `fmt.Println(re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1))`

Comment: Have you tried to look in the documentation? There just might be a method for this.